# How to repeat an unknown dimension in Keras for both backends

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

For example (I can do this with Theano without a problem):

```
# log_var has shape --> (num, )
# Mean has shape --> (?, num)
std_var = T.repeat(T.exp(log_var)[None, :], Mean.shape[0], axis=0)
```

With TensorFlow I can do this:

```
std_var = tf.tile(tf.reshape(tf.exp(log_var), [1, -1]), (tf.shape(Mean)[0], 1))
```

But I don't know how to do the same for Keras, may be like this:

```
std_var = K.repeat(K.reshape(K.exp(log_var), [1, -1]), Mean.get_shape()[0])
```

or

```
std_var = K.repeat_elements(K.exp(log_var), Mean.get_shape()[0], axis=0)
```

... because `Mean` has unknown dimension at axis 0.

I need this for a custom layer output:

```
return K.concatenate([Mean, Std], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keras has an abstraction layer `keras.backend` which you seem to have found already (you refer to it as `K`). This layer provides all the functions for both Theano and TensorFlow you will need.

Say your TensorFlow code works, which is

```
std_var = tf.tile(tf.reshape(tf.exp(log_var), [1, -1]), (tf.shape(Mean)[0], 1))
```

then you can translate it to the abstract version by writing it like this:

```
std_var = K.tile(K.reshape(K.exp(log_var), (1, -1)), K.shape(Mean)[0])
```

Both Theano and TensorFlow support the unknown axis syntax (`-1` for unknown axes) so this is not a problem.

On a side note I am not sure whether your TF code is correct though. You reshape to `(1, -1)`, meaning that the dimension of axis 0 will be 1. I think what you rather want to do is to do this:

```
std_var = K.tile(K.reshape(K.exp(log_var), (-1, num)), K.shape(Mean)[0])
```

Comment: You are right - the shape in tf becomes 1. It's better to put -1 there.
And yes - I import Keras backend as follows:
from keras import backend as K
...but Keras doesn't have tile function - but I can manually check the backend version in this place and choose implementation, but it's not so convenient

Comment: It does. Since November of 2015. Update your Keras ;) ([proof 1](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/1.0.7/keras/backend/theano_backend.py#L475), [proof 2](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blame/1.0.7/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L762))

Comment: You a right - I just confused by tf.repeat, which Keras doesn't have instead of tile

Comment: Alright then :) As a side note, there is `K.repeat` and `K.repeat_elements`.